# Incorrect UITableViewCell gets highlighed when dequeued

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have written a subclass of UITableViewCell to allow horizontal swipe to give some actions to users. Here is what I am doing:

1. Create a scrollView
2. Create a buttonView and add in scrollView.
3. Create a UIButton and add all cell controls as subview to it. Add in scroll view.
4. Add scrollView to cell contentView.

For #3 I am setting the highlighted image to give a feel of user tap like in normal cell.

The issue is when my table view is loaded on iOS 6 with 6 cells and user tap on any of the cell, cell gets highlighted properly and the details are shown properly for the tapped cell. But if user scrolls up and first cell is re-used and user tap on the top cell (which is second row), cell next to it gets highlighted. If user scrolls up and purge 2 cells and tap on the top cell, cell 2 cells down it gets highlighted. Although tapped cell shows the data of the correct cell.

Any clue?

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)iStyle reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)iReuseIdentifier andMenuButtonDetails:(NSArray *)iMenuButtonDetails {
if ((self = [super initWithStyle:iStyle reuseIdentifier:iReuseIdentifier])) {
    self.catchWidth = kMenuButtonWidth * [iMenuButtonDetails count];

    self.scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) + self.catchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.scrollView];

    self.scrollViewButtonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) - self.catchWidth, kScreenOrigin, self.catchWidth, CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds))];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.scrollViewButtonView];

    if ([iMenuButtonDetails count]) {
        // Adding menu buttons to the cell.
        CGFloat anXOffset = kScreenOrigin;
        for (NSDictionary *aMenuButton in iMenuButtonDetails) {
            if ([aMenuButton containsObjectForKey:kTitleKey]) {
                UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(anXOffset, kScreenOrigin, kMenuButtonWidth, kCellHeight64)];
                [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                if ([aMenuButton containsObjectForKey:kButtonTagKey])
                    aButton.tag = [[aMenuButton stringForKey:kButtonTagKey] intValue];
                aButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kScreenOrigin, 2.0, kScreenOrigin, 2.0);
                aButton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
                [aButton.titleLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                [aButton setTitle:[aMenuButton stringForKey:kTitleKey] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                if ([aMenuButton objectForKey:kButtonColorKey]) {
                    aButton.backgroundColor = [aMenuButton objectForKey:kButtonColorKey];
                }
                [self.scrollViewButtonView addSubview:aButton];
                anXOffset += kMenuButtonWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    self.scrollViewContentView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.scrollViewContentView.frame = CGRectMake(kScreenOrigin, kScreenOrigin, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));

    if (![Utilities isIOS7orAbove]) {
        [self.scrollViewContentView addTarget:self action:@selector(cellHighlighted) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [self.scrollViewContentView addTarget:self action:@selector(cellCancelHighlight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragExit];
    }
    [self.scrollViewContentView addTarget:self action:@selector(selectCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.scrollViewContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImage *aBGHighlightedImage = nil;

    if ([Utilities isIOS7orAbove]) {
        aBGHighlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kCellHighlightedImageIOS7];
    } else {
        aBGHighlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kCellHighlightedImageIOS6];
    }

    [self.scrollViewContentView setBackgroundImage:[aBGHighlightedImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:11.0f topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.scrollViewContentView];


    [self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:self.imageView];
    [self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:self.textLabel];
    [self.scrollViewContentView addSubview:self.detailTextLabel];
}

- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.scrollViewContentView.enabled = YES;
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)iTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)iIndexPath {
    MyTableViewCell *aCell = (MyTableViewCell *)[iTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    if (!aCell) {
        aCell = [[MyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier" andMenuButtonDetails:aMenuButtons];
    }

    // Set data on cell now

    return aCell
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: You need to reset the selection status in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: @Paulw11 What do you mean by reset? I tried by setting the cell selection style to none in cellForRowAtIndexPath but it did not help.

Comment: You seem to managing the highlight and selection appearance through your own action handlers. When a cell is reused you need to make sure that the cell is reset so that it shows highlighted or not according to the current selection state of each row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if there is something I'm missing here, but it seems like you're adding a ton of complexity to your class for no reason. Are you familiar with `UICollectionView`?

Here's an example implementation (which scrolls horizontally):

```
@interface asdf () <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UICollectionView *collectionView;
@end

@implementation asdf

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero collectionViewLayout:self.collectionViewLayout];
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:self.collectionView];

        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([UICollectionViewCell class]);
        [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:className];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.collectionView.frame = self.view.bounds;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
{
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    return layout;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([UICollectionViewCell class]);
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:className forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // This is for dequeuing
    NSInteger tag = 12324;
    UIView *view = [cell viewWithTag:tag];
    if (view)
        [view removeFromSuperview];

    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    view.tag = tag;

    // Add all of your subviews to the view property

    [cell addSubview:view];

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.bounds.size.width, 50);
}

@end
```

I wrote this quickly as a sample, so it's not tailored specifically to what you're building, but this should give you a nice idea of how simple it is to implement a `UICollectionView`.

This answer may come across as random for what you're asking, but when possible, you should always try to use what Apple provides over what you would spend precious hours re-inventing the wheel w/ & likely experience random nuances like yours.